# Altering my regex to see any non-numeric character?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var text1 = "this is %60.94 correct?"
var text2 = "is this %45?"
var text3 = "looks like %45.5/%54.5."
var text4 = "what about 5 or 10 = %22.5.2."
```

right now I'm using this, `text.match(/%[^\s\/\,]+/g)`, but it doesn't handle the more edge cases cases.

**I need the be able to stop at any non-numeric character except for the first `.`.**

Any pointers on how to modify the regex to do this would be great. Here is the output I would want from each.

```
text1.match(regex) -> [60.94]
text2.match(regex) -> [45]
text3.match(regex) -> [45.5, 54.5]
text4.match(regex) -> [22.5]
```

Thanks for any help.

**sorry, rules: after any % sign to any non-numeric character except the first instance of a `.`**

also: finding all instances is important

Comment: Why should text3 won't return 54.5 also why won't text4 return `[5,10,22.5]` or similar?

Comment: if %.2 do you want to capture .2 ?

Comment: yes, that would be the correct output

Comment: edited with rules, sorry guys skiped over that part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex can be simply this:

```
/%(\d+(\.\d+)?)/
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FkgKz/1/)

Comment: Can you check my edit? would this work in the case of `text4`?

Comment: @boom. It's hard to follow the rules... Can you define them please. Why the values of text3 and text4 are different?

Comment: just extending upon gdoron's work with a very minor edit seems to capture #4 properly as well:    %(\d+(.?\d+))?   It's hard to see in the comment, but I just prepended the % sign.  A solid regex tester I've found is http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: @STLRick. You can add tilde to every side of the code in a comment to make it highlight like a code, example: `\`Code here\``

Comment: @STLRick. `You welcome... :)` BTW I think my finally regex is better.

Comment: Yeah this is perfect, the only problem is that I need to find every instance and output an array. Can this be done with `/g/ and match?

Comment: @boom. It does work in your demo, though you will need to ignore the leading `%` in the matches.

Comment: @gordon yeah that's ok i can remove them after unless it's really simple to add a rule to parse them out

Comment: @christophe oh crap, really?

Comment: @boom. Simply change from `\d+` to `\d*?` not a big deal at all.

Comment: @gdoron changing \d+ to \d* will match % (and return an empty string)

Comment: @Christophe. True! so... this should be fine, now... `/%(\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.d+)/`

Comment: @Christophe. Actually I'm not fully understand how your regex is working this why I didn't upvote it. and the regex above isn't like yours. Anyway, I'm going to sleep now. Good night.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
/%(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)/g
```

(edited for edge cases)